# Sci fi book from kindle unlimited about a teen mercenary who joins a military academy and gets an AI implant in his head called Chief

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi

It centers around the main character and his AI assistant "Chief" that he was able to have implanted into his mind due to something called a "gemini gene". The human character and alien characters also part of the academy. The first book has the main character join the ace program and a test in VR.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  It sounds like you think it's the first book of a series?  Please provide all the details you can think of, down to character descriptions (what did the aliens look like?) and the cover art.

Comment: @Spar - Someone has attempted to edit this question to state that the correct answer is Joshua Anderle's _Animus_ series. If that person is you, and you can no longer access to the account you used to post this question, please merge your new account with the old one by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). This will enable you to post comments in this thread again, edit the question without approval from others, and marked a correct answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), if one is posted.

Comment: Also, if you found the book/series you were looking for, you should post the answer as an actual answer -- via the 'Your Answer' field below -- rather than editing it into the question. You can do this with a new account, but you won't be able to mark the answer as accepted unless you use the same account you used to post the question, or merge your new account with that one.

Answer (score 8):

It looks as though the OP found the books and attempted to edit this into the question. I'll add this community wiki answer as a placeholder until the OP posts their own answer.

The books are the [Animus series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/251995-animus) by Joshua Anderle. The protagonist is *Kaiden*. The first mention of the *Gemini gene* is:

> “What was it you discovered?” Kaiden queried as he took small sips from his glass.
>
> “There were people with a certain genetic trait—we call it the Gemini factor—who can gain enhanced compatibility with these waves. Through it, they and their EI can actually be on a similar plane or wavelength with one another. Through this, they gain knowledge much quicker and can use it practically at a much faster rate than we normally see.”
>
> Kaiden started to fit the pieces together. “So I’m here because—”
>
> “From what we have discovered, you have this trait,” Laurie finished with a smile.

The AI assistants are called *EI* rather than *AI* (I'm not sure we ever discover what the acronym stands for) and Kaiden does indeed call his *Chief*:

> Kaiden had forgotten about that. He supposed it wasn’t like he could merely pop open the back of his head and replace the thing. He mulled it over and gave another shrug. “Chief ain’t such a bad name. I’ll be sure to comb over the rest carefu—”
>
> “EI, designated Chief, shall begin start-up sequence requesting user preferences. Expected time for set-up approximately five to six hours.”

Answer (score -6):

Probably Old Man's War by John Scalzi
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Man%27s_War

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you explain how this matches the question?  Note that Perry is about as far from a "teen mercenary" as it's possible to get.

Comment: Thank you. He both is and isn't a teenage mercenary. "Perry's mind is transferred to a new body based on his genetic material. His new body is a younger version of himself, ..."

Comment: John Perry definitely doesn't call his BrainPal "Chief", and there is nothing about a "gemini gene" facilitating an implant.